# Entity Framework 7 Include() not working as expected

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

EF7 fills contained navigation properties even when not requested. For example, I have the below entities.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

My fetch query is as below.

```
ctx.Employees.Where(e => e.Gender == "Male").Include(e => e.Department)
```

I get `Department` property of `Employee` object filled – which is as expected as I have an `Include` for `Department`. I find that `Department.Employees` is also filled but partially (only with male employees). I have not specified an `Include` for `Department.Employees`, but it is still getting populated. Is this behavior by design? Is there any way to avoid fetching `Department.Employees` in this scenario?

I am using EF7 NuGet package with version 7.0.0-rc1-final.

Comment: Do you have lazy loading enabled? If so, `Department.Employees` may be getting populated on a second query. Did you run SQL Profiler to find out the exact query(ies) sent to the database?

Comment: There is no lazy load happening. SQL Profiler shows only as single query:

SELECT [e].[EmployeeId], [e].[DepartmentId], [e].[Gender], [e].[Name], [d].[DepartmentId], [d].[Name]
FROM [Employee] AS [e]
INNER JOIN [Department] AS [d] ON [e].[DepartmentId] = [d].[DepartmentId]
WHERE [e].[Gender] = 'Male'

Comment: Just a FYI, Lazy loading is not supported in EF7, at least for now

Answer (score 4):

That is the normal behavior of EF. When you execute your query, all the entities you load is going to be attached to your context. So, EF is not executing another query and loading `Department.Employees` partially, those employees were  loaded earlier when you execute your query. In summary, when you consult `Department.Employees` navigation property, EF is going to fill that property with the employees that you load with your query filtering by `Gender`.

### Update:

As I pointed out in my comment above, Lazy Loading is not supported in EF7. If you want to avoid that Json.NET serializes that property, you can use the attribute [`JsonIgnore`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm) over that property or you can create a custom class (DTO) to project your query and fill only the properties that you need. I also recommend take a look to [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) if you decide to use this last solution.

Comment: No new query is executed when I enumerate `Department.Employees`. I am assuming that it is because EF7 is yet to support lazy load.

Irrespective of the lazy load support, I still want to avoid filling `Department.Employees`. This is because I am serializing the result and do not want the second level incomplete list inside `Department`. Using `PreserveReferencesHandling` setting of Json.Net or setting the serialization depth are some options for me. But, it is most efficient to just avoid creating the collection objects that I do not need.

Comment: you have eagerly loaded both tables, and EF will populate the context with all the entries. Relationship fixup will then populate all navigation properties regarding the other items in the context. if you do not want the inverse navigation properties to be populated, use two contexts and populate the navigation properties on both ends yourself.